# Captive portal Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I have been working with a captive portal which basically needs to block everything except for a domain where a login through Facebook takes place before allowing users to freely navigate.

I have been unable to block Facebook and allow users at the same time to login through it.

I have to either allow people to access Facebook completely or block it completely, there is no in-between ( just allow them to login )

Is there any way that the login process can be handled independently allowing me to keep the site blocked from usage on the network?
a) through an iframe
b) through an alternative url or Facebook subdomain that allows me to keep Facebook blocked?

Thanks!

Comment: i want to do almost the same but with a form where the user put the email. how can i let them navigate after the user press the button of login? what tools i need

Comment: I would recommend you to look for a router with dd-wrt installed. The software includes some captive portal options you can customize to your needs.

Comment: i installed openwrt..but i dont know how can i let them navigate after the login form

Comment: Once the user accepts the capitve portal form, they should be able to navigate.

Comment: yes but how can i do that?

Comment: Check the wiki on ddwrt portal: https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Captive_Portal

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable facebook login in your captive portal unfortunately you have to allow facebook access to the users, that's the only way, because the login screen is hosted in facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I can answer you question in entirety without more details - it's also been a while since I've played with the Facebook API.  But, some food for thought (while leaving the details up to you):

Depending on what you are using as a captive portal, I would consider using Facebook's API - i.e. serving a log-in form on your captive portal (with the API key on your server) and having the auth take place between your captive portal and Facebook's server.  Facebook's API has a lot of options/information (PHP, JavaScript, Rails, etc.), depending on what you are comfortable with.

The benefit to this would be that it wouldn't require you to poke holes in your captive portal - i.e. the log-in would be local (as far as the client was concerned), and the server would handle interactions between the Facebook API and the user.  From there you can easily manage connections through your captive portal.

If you need more help, please provide some more details about your setup (os, software, etc).  here are some resources about log-in through Facebook:

http://cacovsky.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/login-with-facebook-php-sdk-a-tutorial/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Comment: Thanks for the response Kevin. The captive portal redirects to a web app where I wish the Facebook login to be. The web app is ruby on rails.

Comment: I've been trying to do server side authentication, but always at some point the user needs to go to Facebook.com... The link you posted for the php sdk tutorial needs to access facebook.com

Comment: Gustavo, not a problem.  As you said, once the web app is white-listed it will allow the user to browse freely on the given domain.  I don't really see a way to change that.  Like I said, the only solution I see is collecting credentials locally in a walled garden, then having the server authorize with Facebook's API.  I assume when you refer to a captive portal you are talking about authorizing a client for internet connection (like on a hotspot)?  What software are you using as a captive portal?  What is your server running?  Linux?  Windows?

Comment: Yeah, but the access to Facebook.com should be taking place from behind the captive portal.  From there it would just be matter of tweaking your firewall to allow a connection between the gateway and Facebook's API.  Obviously the goal of the walled garden would be to block ALL connections downstream from the gateway.  But allow the server itself to access Facebook.com, whether your using Facebook to auth the user, or another protocol, like RADIUS, your server itself can't be subject to the captive portal, otherwise your S.O.L., as they say.

Comment: The captive portal is on dd-wrt (no cat splash). I don't want people just pushing the ok button, I would like them to register through Facebook before getting full unrestricted access. I wouldn't have a problem changing to another firmware if there are better options.

Comment: Ahh, I got you.  Well, I haven't looked at it for a while, but doesn't NoCatSplash have a timeout feature?  Your user could have a free x seconds of internet in which they can log-in to Facebook otherwise they get disconnected?  But I do see your problem because I forgot that Facebook Connect requires the user to OK information sharing before your app has access.  Sorry for the confusion.  I would say have a timeout on their connection.  Otherwise, you could cheat and have a login/signup form on your server which submits to Facebook.  Think MITM without scraping creds.

Comment: Yeah, nocatsplash has a timeout but it is for once the form has been accepted not for the login part. I have looked for modified code but haven't found anything, maybe I will have to dive into it and find out how to do it manually modifying nocatsplash files.

Comment: the thing is Captive portal don't allow to download huge JavaScript (which exactly Oauth2.0 authentication has)